# for next loop show error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

hi i am creating vba code and here for loop shows error 13 type mismatch

```
For x = 0 To 4
ActiveCell.Offset(0, " & x & ").FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-7]C[-3]"
Next x
```

i try 
`dim x as integer` and `dim x as Long` nothing works plz help

Comment: No need for your `"&X&"` bit, just pass X directly `ActiveCell.Offset(0, x).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-7]C[-3]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you pass X to your `activecell.offset(` statement (`" & x & "`) is the way you would pass it if you referenced x in a worksheet formula through vba. This is entirely redundant in this case as vba can handle x as an integer (or long) directly. Therefore:

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 0 To 4
ActiveCell.Offset(0, x).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[-7]C[-3]"
Next x
```

Will work exactly as expected.